# Flip (mirror image) form field or page in Acrobat PDF

Tags: pdf, javascript

Is it possible to flip a form field OR flip an entire page horizontally using javascript in Acrobat 9 ? Either one would work for our purposes.

The Acrobat SDK gives the ability to rotate, but we need a flip in order to end up with a mirror image.

[image: horizontal PDF form flip]

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pitstop](https://www.enfocus.com/en/products/pitstop-pro) plugin -> Global Changes -> Standard -> Page -> Flip Page Content